# Spark related jars cannot be resolved in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-spark

I'm new to Spark so am trying to setup a project from the book Learning Spark: Lightning-Fast Big Data Analysis. The book uses version 1.3 but I've only got 2.1.1 so am trying to work around a few differences.

All the Spark related jars that I'm importing into my Java project have a "import org.apache cannot be resolved". I know it's because the project cannot find the jar files specified.

I can manually add each by going to Build Path > Configure Build path and adding them to the Libraries section but I think I shouldn't need to do this. The project uses Maven so I believe if I have the Spark dependencies configured correctly in my pom.xml it should work. Is this correct?

I also set the following environment variables:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/Users/mymac/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/
export PATH="$SPARK_HOME/bin/:$PATH"
```

Are there any others I should be aware of?

Here's the contents of my pom.xml:

```
<project>
  <groupId>com.oreilly.learningsparkexamples.mini</groupId>
  <artifactId>learning-spark-mini-example</artifactId>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <name>example</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.8</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.5</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>${java.version}</source>
            <target>${java.version}</target>
          </configuration>
    </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Yes you are correct, maven should download the jars automatically during first build or launch. Did it happen? Maybe you need to install the maven plugin as well. Also try the eclipse "organize Imports" command (Ctrl+Shift+o) in one of your classes to check if the package names have changed between spark 1 and 2. it will import the correct packages automatically if the build path (with or without Maven) is setup correctly.

Comment: I had already tried "orgfanize imports". I have the Maven plugin installed but noticed an update for it so ran that but it's still the same. I ran mvn clean && mvn build && mvn package in a terminal and it compiles and runs without any issue. The problem seems to be with Eclipse.

Comment: Got it sorted through some trial and error. I initially had it setup in my workspace as a Java project. I removed this, re-created in the workspace as a general project, then converted it to a Maven project. I probably should have just set it up as a Maven project at the start but you live and learn!

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. I switched from eclipse to netbeans due to experiencing lots of similar mysterious issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be setup as a Maven project, not a Java project. In my case to resolve deleted the project from my workspace, re-created it in the workspace as a general project, then converted it to a Maven project. I probably should have just set it up as a Maven project at the start.